# How to make a popup on a node's content using the colorbox module?

Tags: javascript

In Drupal 7, all I had to do to add a popup with colorbox was add the CSS class colorbox to the link to create a nice popup.  Now, using Drupal 8, I cannot figure out how to do this.

I can add colorbox to my fields, but I want to add it directly to the link `<a class="colorbox" href"".../a>` in the content body, but it is not working.  I cannot figure out how to use inline colorbox either, if that is the solution.

How can I add the popup?

Answer (score -1):

For creating pop-up's in colorbox, you can simply use Bootstrap Modal Window.

Don't forget to include the below ones:
1. bootstrap.min.css 
2. jquery.min.js 
3. bootstrap.min.js

FULL WORKING CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Small Modal</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Small Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>This is a small modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Bootstrap Modal Window]